# Share the sound of my PC and play it on onther PC in the same network?

Tags: windows, networking, audio

I want to play all my sounds (like playing a music in Winamp, Watching Movie in Windows media player, May be Skype calls) from my laptop through my PC's 6.1 Audio system. Both systems are connected to same rooter. Any possible solution ?

Comment: Which OS are you Using ?

Comment: Windows 7 on both.